# UnrecoverableKeyException

Tags: tomcat, ssl, server

- Passwords are the same
- User has permissions

Error log:

```
> 2017-09-14 15:37:21,186 ERROR [main] 
> o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol Failed to start end point
> associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
>             at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250)
>             at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193)
>             at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
>             at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>             at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>             at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.boot.BitbucketServerApplication.start(BitbucketServerApplication.java:247)
>             at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.boot.BitbucketServerApplication.main(BitbucketServerApplication.java:83)
>             at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>             at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>             at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.launcher.BitbucketServerLauncher.start(BitbucketServerLauncher.java:151)
>             at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.launcher.BitbucketServerLauncher.main(BitbucketServerLauncher.java:99)
>             ... 11 frames trimmed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.
What did you before? Did it work once? etc.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: RTFM

> Both `ssl.key-store-password` and `ssl.key-password` require explicit configuration. Even if you did not configure both values in the `server.xml` file, values for both entries need to be explicitly set in `bitbucket.properties` to secure Bitbucket with SSL.